# How to select clients who signed contracts with all subsidiaries?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to select clients who signed contracts with all subsidiaries?

```
R2
    UID | Subsidiary
    1   | 1
    1   | 2
    1   | 3
    2   | 1
    2   | 2
    3   | 1
    3   | 1
```

Could you help me with this question?

Comment: How [do _you_ think](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) you should do it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Francly speaking we have just started our database course at the university. Well, the lecturer delivered his lecture and gave us a task to be done on a sheet of paper. So, I have never touched Oracle in practice. I tried today, but failed to cope with it and decided to cope with it later after a pratcical lesson. But anyway the task is the task. I can only guess what can be done to this. I guess we should use somethin like SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM R2 GROUP BY Subsidiary HAVING ... Well, I don't know how to select unique subsidiaries. Pardon me for such a question, but I hope for your help.

Comment: Some people on SO take a dim view of "homework" questions.  But I think we're supposed to help people regardless of their status, providing the question is worthwhile *in and of itself*.  The closure as NORQ is wrong, because your question is both understandable and not trivial.

Comment: @APC I agree it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select u_r2.uid
from 
     (select uid
           , count(distinct subsidiary) as u_subs
     from r2
     group by uid )  u_r2
  , 
    (select count (distinct subsidiary) as tot_subs
     from r2) sub_r2
where sub_r2.tot_subs = u_r2.u_subs;
```